# Run Jenkins Build Step in Parallel

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way to run Jenkins build step in parallel.

I know I can run multiple jobs in parallel, but I need to collate the unit test result and code coverage and use it generate a report.

So jobs in parallel might not be achieve the purpose, so I need to run build steps in parallel.

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you achieve this ?

Comment: I'd like to know how you achieved this as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like a job for the [Jenkins Multijob plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin). You can create 2 phases:

Phase 1 : Builds jobs which run in parallel

Phase 2 : Collate results and generate report. You can specify this job to run only after the first phase is complete, and only if its successful etc.

Comment: looks like this plugin is for multiple jobs. Is there anything for multiple steps?

Comment: What do you mean by multiple steps? Can you use pre and post build steps for that?

Comment: This is not the expected answer. the question is to run the build steps in parallel